# Is there a way to access a running docker container on a remote server from my local development enviroment(Sublime)

Tags: ssh, docker, sublimetext3

Currently I can use rsub with sublime to edit remotely but the container is a second layer of ssh that is only accessible from the host machine.

Answer (score 0):

Just curious, how do you use your remote host machine if you even have no ssh  running on it?

Regarding to your question, I think you need to install `openssh-server` directly inside the container and map container's 22 port to the host's custom port. Inside your container you'll have to run some initial process that will launch all the processes you need (like `openssh-server`).

Consider [this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/using_supervisord/) comprehensive example of the use of `supervisord` inside Docker container.